# Magento Cron Job Sales Category

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add all products with a "special price" into a special category using cron jobs. I've got cron.php running successfully however I cannot seem to get the cron to work can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

What I have so far:
app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/ect/config.xml:

```
<crontab>
<jobs>          
    <namespace_productassign>  
        <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule> 
        <run><model>modulename/productassign::assignproduct</model></run>  
    </namespace_productassign>
</jobs>
</crontab>
```

app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Productassign.php:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Productassign {

public function assignproduct () {

    try {

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $productIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()     
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq'=>1))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('neq' => ""))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => ""))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('lt' =>new Zend_Db_Expr('at_price.value')))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(0 => array('date' => true, 'from' =>$tomorrowDate), 1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))), 'left')
             ->getAllIds();
        $newCategories = 68; // Add here your SALE category id

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($newCategories);
        $saleIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
         ->addCategoryFilter($category)
         ->getAllIds();

        $product = (array_values(array_diff($productIds,$saleIds)));

        foreach ($product as $id) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (category_id ,product_id) VALUES ('".$newCategories."', '".$id."')";
            $statement = $write->query($sql);       

        }

        // Working copy of unassign product from Sale Category whose special to date is ended.
        $current_date =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($newCategories);
        $saleIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
         ->addCategoryFilter($category)
         ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('date'=>true, 'lt'=> $current_date))
         ->getAllIds();

        foreach ($saleIds as $id) {

            $sql = "Delete from catalog_category_product where category_id='".$newCategories."' and product_id='".$id."'";              
            $statement = $write->query($sql);       

        }

        /* reindexing           
        3. Catalog URL Rewrites         
        6. Category Products            
        */

        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(3);
        $process->reindexAll();
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(6);
        $process->reindexAll();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Any help would be great, thank you. Do I need to do anything else to make this cron work?

Comment: do you solve u issue?

Comment: Not yet can't find why the cron is not been run. @monojit

Comment: i have used magento cron earlier. make sure your module is working fine. You can use Mage::log("works"); inside assignproduct function for checking whether your function is calling or not.i have used observer.php inside module but i think it's not the issue and i followed http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job link

Comment: also make sure your cron.php is working fine.you can remove all the function from your page and just use Mage::log("works"); for checking and clear cache as well.

Comment: if you see that your module is working fine but cron is not working then create observer.php inside model (class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer) and check whether it;s working or not..

Comment: cron.php outputs works. However from productassign I don't get anything logged. Do I need more than above in my config.xml?

Comment: no,it's ok.you have to write the xml code inside the <config></config> tag and make sure your custom module is working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not sure whats up but I always use this ext to help debug and run cron jobs
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed this the other day, my cron does not seem to show up on the list? Does this mean there is something wrong with the config.xml?